# Unable to generate caption

Tags: floats, pdftex, captions

After I recently changed to a new computer, I re-downloaded texStudio. But the original tex file started to show errors when it was compiled. Unable to generate caption.
I extracted the location of the error. The problem is mainly the use of the `\captionof` command.

When the `\captionof` command is commented out, it can run normally, but if it is uncommented, there will be a `Package caption Error: Should not be used with subtype` subfigure'. \captionof{subfigure}` problem.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum,afterpage}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
%
%%[Yujie]
\usepackage[ruled,lined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
%\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{newfloat}
\usepackage[scaled]{beramono}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{flushend}

\definecolor{keywordcolor}{RGB}{157,0,129}
\definecolor{commentcolor}{RGB}{157,0,129}
\definecolor{numbercolor}{RGB}{120,120,120}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[fileext=frm,placement={!ht},name=Listing]{listing}

%[Yujie] command
\newcommand{\myline}{\vspace{-0.7\baselineskip}\hrulefill\vspace{-0.1\baselineskip}}

\begin{document}
    
    \lipsum[1-5]
    
    \makeatletter
    



\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=parens,labelsep = none}
\begin{listing}[t]
    \noindent
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{0.25\textwidth}
        \begin{framed}
            \begin{lstlisting}[gobble=21, language=C,numbers=left,
                numberstyle={\color{numbercolor}\normalfont},
                numbersep={-0.2cm},keywordstyle={\color{keywordcolor}},
                breaklines=true,
                basicstyle=\linespread{1.3}\footnotesize,
                aboveskip=0em,
                belowskip=0em,tabsize=6
                ]
                if (secret)
                modify line
                else
                access line
            \end{lstlisting}
            \captionof{subfigure}{ Victim function}
        \end{framed}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{0.25\textwidth}
        \begin{framed}
            
            \begin{lstlisting}[gobble=21, language=C,numbers=left,
                numberstyle={\color{numbercolor}\normalfont},
                numbersep={-0.2cm},keywordstyle={\color{keywordcolor}},
                breaklines=true,
                basicstyle=\linespread{1.3}\footnotesize,
                aboveskip=0em,
                belowskip=0em,tabsize=6
                ]
                if (secret)
                access line
                else
                access line
            \end{lstlisting}
%           \captionof{subfigure}{ Victim function}
        \end{framed}
    \end{minipage}%
    %   \caption{WB gadgets for side channel exploitation}
\end{listing}

    \makeatother
    
    \lipsum[6-12]
    
\end{document}
```

I want to save these codes as pictures so that there is no error. But I found the picture is very blurry. The above is generated by `LaTeX listing`, the following is generated by the picture. I don’t know what to do? But I see the code pictures in other papers are very clear. Does anyone know how to do it?
Thanks!
[image]

Comment: The `\captionof`  command is not a command defined in the latex kernel. Uncomment `\usepackage{caption}`.

Comment: The same error will appear after uncommenting.